# Prove that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ inverse have the same order in $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

So there is a question in my lecture notes that I'm not too sure how to approach. It reads as follows:

> Suppose $a$ is invertible modulo $n$. Prove that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same order in $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: How can you express the order of $a$

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$ is an abelian group, so $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is an isomorphism. Orders are preserved under isomorphisms.

Comment: @Prahlad: +1. Taking your argument one step further, the map $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ is an isomorphism between a group and its opposite for _any_ group and consequently, the order of $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are equal. Another consequence is that $ab$ and $ba$ have the same order (in this case, one usually argues that $ab$ and $ba$ are conjugates!) in a group...

Answer (score 2):

$$(a^{-1})^r = 1 (a^{-1})^r =  a^r (a^{-1})^r = (a^{r-1})aa^{-1}(a^{-1})^{r-1} = a^{r-1}(a^{-1})^{r-1} = \cdots = 1.$$
Therefore, $|a^{-1}| \le r$. Now, for all $0 < s < r$, $a^r(a^{-1})^s = a^{r-s} \neq 1$, so $|a^{-1}| \ge r$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about this as such: Consider $a$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{n}$. Then the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ is the same as the subgroup generated by its inverse (why?). Therefore, the order of $a$ is the same as the order of $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all suppose

$|a| = n$

$|a^{-1}| = m$

$(a^{-1})^n = a^{-n} = (a^{n})^{-1}$

so m | n now all we need to prove is that n | m and we will be done

$a = (a^{-1})^{-1}$ $\rightarrow$ $a^m = (a^{-1})^{-1})^m = (a^{-1})^{m})^{-1}$ = 1, so n | m and we are done.